# How do I "close" this responsive dropdown menu after clicking a menu item?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have little to no JavaScript experience, so if someone could help me with this I'd very much appreciate it...

I'm trying to create a responsive menu, but can't seem to figure out how to get the menu to "close" (when in its responsive state) once a menu item has been clicked.

Here is the tutorial I'm using: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_topnav

Also, in the menu's un-responsive state, I'd like the menu items to stay highlighted after being clicked (so the user knows which tab is active).

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think once you navigate (on a real site) it will close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a myFunction() call to the onclick handler of the A tags to be executed upon clicking on the links as the following:

```
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home" onclick="myFunction()">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news" onclick="myFunction()">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" onclick="myFunction()">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about" onclick="myFunction()">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**See demo here:** http://jsbin.com/lafepitopu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

The menu looks like it works. The `href` attributes of your list items don't actually link to anywhere because it's a demo. Create another page with the same code, change your content and link to it from your original page. You'll see the menu collapse upon redirecting to the location specified in your `href`.

If you want to keep a tab highlighted, change it's respective list item class to `class="active"`.

Comment: Sorry. I should've been more clear. I'm using this menu as a "sub-menu" on an existing page, so the menu links are actually just linking to anchor tags that exist on the same page, but Shadi's solution solved that issue. Thanks for your help Michal!